# what is the output if terminating error occurs in move-vm cmdlet

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch, powershell-cmdlet

I know from this move-vm -ErrorAction Stop command that a terminating errors can be caught but will the script stop its execution or will it continue if the command move-vm is in foreach all vms.

```
   foreach ($vms) {
        Try {
            Move-VM -VM $vm_name -Datastore $datastore -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Catch {
            #do something 
        }
       }
```

And also what happens if -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue is used, Will the catch block catch errors.

Comment: With `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` the catch block is not necessary.
With an inner Try / Catch block, the loop will continue on next VM, unless you use `break` in the `catch` block to out from the loop.

Comment: what happens if -ErrorAction Stop is used and error occurs, will execution of script stop or just the move-vm stops and next foreach continues?

Comment: this will be handled by the `catch` block and next will continue.

Comment: So the script wont stop and the loop continues right. Thank you!